# How to feed multiple inputs and outputs from data generator to tensorflow model

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras

This is my model:

```
import tensorflow as tf
from tensorflow.keras import Input, Model


input1 = tf.keras.layers.Input(shape=(None,512 ))
input2 = tf.keras.layers.Input(shape=(None,512))
inputs= tf.keras.layers.Concatenate(axis=1)([input1, input2])
x = tf.keras.layers.Conv1D(filters=16, kernel_size=3, strides=1, padding="causal", activation="relu",input_shape=[None,2,1])(inputs)
x = tf.keras.layers.Bidirectional(tf.keras.layers.GRU(128, activation="tanh", return_sequences=True))(x)
x = tf.keras.layers.Bidirectional(tf.keras.layers.GRU(256, activation="tanh", return_sequences=True))(x)
x = tf.keras.layers.Dense(128, activation="tanh")(x)
o1 = tf.keras.layers.Dense(1, activation="linear",name="ed")(x)
o2 = tf.keras.layers.Dense(1, activation="sigmoid",name="sd")(x)

model = Model(inputs=[input1,input2], outputs=[o1, o2])

model.compile(loss={'ed': 'mean_squared_error', 
                    'sd': 'binary_crossentropy'},
              optimizer='adam',
              metrics={'ed': tf.keras.metrics.MeanSquaredError(name="mean_squared_error", dtype=None),
                       'sd': tf.keras.metrics.BinaryCrossentropy(name="binary_crossentropy", dtype=None, from_logits=False, label_smoothing=0)})
```

It takes two inputs and gives two outputs. Since, my dataset is big I'm feeding the data in batches. Here is my batching function:

```
counter = 0
def batch_generator(timetr,atr, wtr,wbtr, batch_size = 100):


    global counter
    if counter>40030:
        counter = 0

    w = timetr[counter:counter+batch_size,:]
    x = atr[counter:counter+batch_size,:]
    y = wtr[counter:counter+batch_size,:]
    z = wbtr[counter:counter+batch_size,:]
    counter += batch_size
    return [w,x],[y,z]
```

Finally here is my model.fit() function:

```
history = model.fit(batch_generator(timetr,atr,wtr,wbtr,100),epochs=5,verbose=2,steps_per_epoch= 402)
```

The problem is model.fit() is recognising four inputs instead of two inputs and two outputs.
Error:

```
Layer model_1 expects 2 input(s), but it received 4 input tensors. Inputs received: [<tf.Tensor 'IteratorGetNext:0' shape=(1, 512) dtype=float32>, <tf.Tensor 'IteratorGetNext:1' shape=(1, 512) dtype=float32>, <tf.Tensor 'IteratorGetNext:2' shape=(1, 512) dtype=float32>, <tf.Tensor 'IteratorGetNext:3' shape=(1, 512) dtype=int64>]
```

What can I do to pass the last two tensors as output.

Comment: What is the shape of `timetr` ?

Comment: @mujjiga all arrays are (40130,512)